# Orphaned questions asked by deleted users

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-accounts

When a user gets deleted/destroyed, and their questions that don't yet have an accepted answer gets orphaned, they can no longer have an accepted answer.

What's the general guidelines for dealing with these? Do we close them? Delete them?

EDIT: This question differs from [A question should not be deleted by the user deletion algorithm if it has upvoted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199860/a-question-should-not-be-deleted-by-the-user-deletion-algorithm-if-it-has-upvote) - I'm more interested in orphaned questions that haven't yet been answered. We should aim to keep people interested in answering them, even though they don't have the possibility of getting a checkmarked answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A question should not be deleted by the user deletion algorithm if it has upvoted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199860/a-question-should-not-be-deleted-by-the-user-deletion-algorithm-if-it-has-upvote)

Comment: @Rob - Not quite. My question differs in that I'm more interested in keeping people interested in answering questions that don't yet have an answer, knowing that they won't receive a checkmark.

Comment: In that case your question would be closer to a duplicate of one of these:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41852/282094, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89458/282094, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251391/282094, etc. --- **Thank you** for editing your question to clairify how it differs from the suggested duplicates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't treat them any different from a question asked by any other user. Stack Exchange is all about the *content*; the community will tend to upvote the best answer and it will get the most prominent place (on the page itself and in search engine results). In fact, this is often a better indication of whether it's a good answer than the checkmark, as more (knowledgeable) people have contributed to the high score.

Answer (score 4):

I think having an accepted answer to a question is an interesting aside but the best measure of answer quality is the upvoting and downvoting.

A bigger problem than a deleted user no longer being available to accept an answer is that they are no longer available to improve their question so that it becomes answerable. In these cases, you could either edit to improve them, or if what they were trying to ask is not evident, then simply downvote the question for it being not useful.